Google Drive watch does not invoke callback after initial sync
I need to receive a callback whenever a known folder for a user in my enterprise receives new files.
I've setup a service account and gave the domain wide permissions with the Google Drive Scope.
However, no callbacks are received in my endpoint. It does not matter if I use files.watch or changes.watch
I get the first sync callback but no more callbacks are received, no matter what I do in the folder.
Relevant snippets of the code I'm using:
//Creating the credential
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(credentialJson).CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithUser(userToImpersonate);

//Creating the service
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = _configuration.ApplicationName
});


// Create a new watch request with an expiration time
// WatchChannelExpirationInMinutes = 300
Channel body = new Channel
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Type = "web_hook",
    Address = _configuration.CallbackUrl,
    Expiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_configuration.WatchChannelExpirationInMinutes).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
};
// Find the user's folder to watch
var folderId = JGGoogleDriveDriver.FindFolderId(usernameToWatch, string.Empty, _configuration.UserFolderName); //This returns the correct folderId
             

// Set up the watch request on the folder
var request = service.Files.Watch(body, folderId);

Channel response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

//Log result - everything looks ok
_logger.LogInformation($"Files Watch channel ID: {response.Id} for username {usernameToWatch} - expires {(response.Expiration.HasValue ? $"on {DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(response.Expiration.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}" : "at an unknown time")}");

The sync callback I receive is empty with the following headers:
{
  "user-agent": "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)",
  "content-length": "0",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "x-forwarded-for": "74.125.210.64",
  "x-forwarded-host": "<myserver.com>",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
  "x-goog-channel-expiration": "Fri, 12 Jul 2024 22:47:59 GMT",
  "x-goog-channel-id": "2e322d09-d0f4-4ae3-9e20-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "x-goog-message-number": "1",
  "x-goog-resource-id": "aaaaaa-ielTQ5JGeHicJERaaaaa",
  "x-goog-resource-state": "sync",
  "x-goog-resource-uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/aaaaaaczeElbmNfWchnVrgDs4jraaaaaa?alt=json&null"
}

The strangest thing is that a few days ago this same code was working and I was receiving lots of "update" callbacks!
Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue or point me in the solution direction?
Thanks in advance
I've tried setup changes.watch instead of files.watch but the behaviour was exactly the same
EDIT:
I've tested the same code today, after the weekend, and now I'm getting update callbacks.
Is it possible that google blocked temporary and silently my channel registrations, returning only the sync callback but nothing more?
My hypothesis is that I've registered too many channels while developing and testing the feature so that google itself stopped registering on it's side, but without returning any warning or error.
After the weekend went by, all those channels dissapeared on google side, so, this morning, I've been able again to register them. Makes sense?
Is there any way I can check the number of current active channels?
I've submitted a bug issue to google regarding this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/353080253
